# Algolia search suggestion like google/amazon

Tags: algolia

I am working on implement the google/amazon like search using the algolia but using the algolia autocomplete it is not easy. as i would like the user query to save on algolia so when next time same search is done it would show from there.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to get what you are exactly looking for! So thought to share few reference hoping that this will guide you to get started.

> I am working on implement the google/amazon like search using the algolia but using the algolia autocomplete it is not easy

Autocomplete is possible in Algolia. As someone enters a search query, autocomplete starts suggesting completed versions of the phrase to help the user refine their search results.

- https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/what-is-instantsearch/js/
- https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/ui-and-ux-patterns/autocomplete/how-to/creating-an-autocomplete-textarea/js/

> as i would like the user query to save on algolia so when next time same search is done it would show from there.

This is kind of showing their past searches to make their search experience better.

- https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/solutions/ecommerce/autocomplete/tutorials/recent-searches/